# AngularJS: Parse HTML events in timeline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools

During the debugging of my angularjs application, I found a lot of *parse html* events in the dev tools. [image]

The timeline says that this event is invoked by `jQuery.extend.buildFragment` and it's hard for me to understand, what directive invokes *parse html*.

How can I detect, what exactly causes *parse html* events? Probably the reason could be in the `ng-repeat`, but I'm not sure.

These events slow down `$scope.$apply` as well.

Comment: which tool is this? maybe the tool just logs when it parses a code line to analyze it?

Comment: it's a chrome dev tools, I guess, it just log browser events

Comment: Try exploring the call stack, it's in bottom of the screenshot, interesting lines are truncated :( .

Comment: @Andrey sure, here is a full callstack http://i.imgur.com/Yn7NQMJ.png jquery handle data here :)

Comment: I suggest you to find what directive is compiling in that call stack. Probably using debugger or logs. Cause it's hard to say, so many directives in angular.

Comment: @Andrey unfortunately I have thousands directives on the page and I can't find exactly directive. That's the reason, why I put a question on SO

Comment: every partial html in angular will trigger that, like ng-includes, ng-repeats, directives. and using jQuery will give you a lot of overhead for initalize jquey instances. jQuery or jQlite buildFragment is called when you or directives or angular call element.html('something tags'), its write to innerHTML which cause parse HTML events and angular loop those children to find more directives and untill its complete.

Comment: @YOU thanks, you're right. Something like ng-repeat or ng-include makes this. You can make your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every partial html in angular will trigger Parse HTML event, like ng-includes, ng-repeats, directives, and $digest cycles.

Also using jQuery will give you a lot of overhead for initalize jquery instances. jQuery or jQlite buildFragment is called when you or directives or angular call element.html('something tags'), which in turn write to innerHTML which cause parse HTML event in browser and angular walk those children to find more directives and compile those until its complete.

To minimize those, you need to batch process those, but nature of angular will be hard to do directly. May be you can try to use one-time binding syntax :: in angular 1.3+ or make less watchers, so angular won't have to parse html again and again.