# AngularJS: how to optimize nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optimization, angularjs-directive

I have the following template for directive `item` in angular. Item contains property `type` in it's scope. Based on this type I need to render different template.

```
<item ng-repeat="myItem in items track by myItem.id">
  <div ng-switch="::myItem.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="type1">
      Some complex html with a couple of ng-if and ng-include
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="type2">
      Some complex html with a couple of ng-if and ng-include
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="type3">
      Some complex html with a couple of ng-if and ng-include
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="type4">
      Some complex html with a couple of ng-if and ng-include
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="type5">
      Some complex html with a couple of ng-if and ng-include
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="type6">
      Some complex html with a couple of ng-if and ng-include
    </div>
  </div>
</item>
```

I'd like to rework every `ng-switch-when` in the standalone directive, and improve performance of ng-repeat (right now it has to make ng-include and set innerHTML for every item and it's a heavy operation for the browser even for list of 50 items).

**So my questions are:**

- how to rework ng-switch-when into standalone directives
- how to improve performance of the ng-repeat in this case

**Update:**

- The question related to the [AngularJS: Parse HTML events in timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697644/angularjs-parse-html-events-in-timeline) it's one the reasons why I would like to optimize current structure.
- added missed `track by`
- a lot of `ng-if` and `ng-include` statements is needed because every *widget* that represented by `ng-switch-when` has it's own logic and will be rendered based on some other parameters of `myItem`.

The problem also that I need to fully rebuild this list of item by some user action.

**BTW:**

In react I can do something like:

```
render: function() {
  //it's for two items, but can be extended for any number of templates
  var child = this.props.type === 'Type A' ? <TemplateA /> : <TemplateB />;

  return child;
}
```

Comment: Guessing by your code, I would say that the `switch` clause is exclusive. Is  my assumption correct? What about the content of each case - is it similar or completely different? Because without further details I don't see any possible improvements regarding the `switch` clause.

Comment: @alesc the templates inside ng-switch-on are similar, but have some differencies, not the same. I'm not sure that understand your question, please, ask everything if it's not clear.

Comment: @alesc inside every `ng-switch-on` I have to check state of `myItem` and based on it I'm including appropriate template. E.g. inside the `type3`: `ng-if="myItem.hasSomething && myItem.state.isReady  ng-include="some-template.html"`

Comment: You could omit the `switch` and have only one child - a directive. Then this directive would dynamically change the template (HTML elements). If some HTML elements are similar, then the directive could re-use it. If nothing can be re-used, then you end up with the same switch-like code inside of your directive. If this is the case, don't change anything as you will not improve anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need a lot of IF statements, and why you want use directives for that, but i can help you with advice for ng-repeat.

Use `track by $index` in ng-repeat to improve performance. And check articles about Angular performance, like this: [11 Tips to Improve AngularJS Performance](http://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance/)

Also, if you have interface with a lot of elements which need to render, may be you should look in ReactJS which is faster for rendering.

Comment: Thanks, I use it, just missed it in the my snippet.

Comment: a lot of if statements is needed for now, the widget inside `ng-switch-when` has it's own logic :)